# Spring-Hibernate: How to define default values when using related objects

Tags: hibernate, model-view-controller, spring, forms

I have a Spring 3 MVC app sing Hibernate as ORM. All works fine. But a question:

I have a web interface to create new objects, say a new CUSTOMER. Each CUSTOMER has a STATUS. The STATUS-Table has predefined values. The CUSTOMER-Table has a status_id field to joind the information.

When displaying a list of CUSTOMERS, I can access the CUSTOMER.STATUS property and get the right object baed on the id.

BUT: How can I define a standard status for NEW CUSTOMERS? I have a web interface with a dropdown.

```
<form:select path="status">
<form:option value="0" label="- Please Select -" />
<form:options items="${customerStatuses}" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

This always shows the "Please Select" text because it seems like the value is always 0??? How can I change this to my individually selected standard status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You controller needs to take care of this. I would do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/new-customer-form" })
public String showNewCustomerForm(ModelMap model) {
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
    newCustomer.setStatus(statusRepository.getDefaultStatus());
    model.addAttribute("customer", newCustomer);
    model.addAttribute("customerStatuses", statusRepository.getAllStatuses());
    return "customer-form";
}
```

As a matter of fact, the "- Please Select -" label will not show anymore because your status is always filled.

(I hope I understood your question correctly this time.)

Comment: But I need the STATUS table because a) each status has some more attributes than oly a name and I configure those attributes in the table columns, b) the statuses can be configured depending on the logged in user.

Comment: Is there any way to define the default status_id? That should pull the right status object fro the table, right? Because the default be present no matter what the user adds or removes from his individual status list.

Comment: Ok. So I create a new customer and then have to call the respective setter. And I have to do this in my Controller and can't define it right in the class. Not perfect, but at least I now know that I can stop looking for another solution. Thanks